# Can we catch exception from child class method in base class in C#?

Tags: c#

In an interview interviewer asked me this question. 
Can we catch exception thrown by a child class method in base class? 
I said no, but he said yes it's possible. 
So I want to know is this possible at all and if yes please give me any practical example. 
You don't have to call base class method. 
Thanks.

Comment: In what context? If you mean a virtual method which is overriden directly, then there's no way for a base class to catch an exception thrown in the child implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            SomeOtherMethod();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public virtual void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I can be overridden");
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception("Oh no!");
    }
}
```

`SomeMethod`, defined on the base class, calls another method `SomeOtherMethod` of the same object and catches any exceptions. If you override `SomeOtherMethod` in some child class and it throws an exception, then this is caught in `SomeMethod` defined on the base class. The language used in your question is a little ambiguous (technically at runtime it is still the instance of `ChildClass` doing the exception handling) but I assume that this is what your interviewer was getting at.

Another possibility (again, depending on the interpretation) is that an instance of a base class calls a method of a *different* object that inherits said base class, which throws an exception (and then catches the exception):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var thing = new ChildClass();
        try
        {
            thing.ThrowMyException();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public void ThrowMyException()
    {
        throw new Exception("Oh no!");
    }
}
```

Here, when `BaseClass.SomeMethod` is called, an *instance of* a base class catches an exception thrown in *another instance of* a child class.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple example in which a base class is catching an exception from a derived class.

```
abstract class Base
{
    // A "safe" version of the GetValue method.
    // It will never throw an exception, because of the try-catch.
    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
    {
        try
        {
            value = GetValue(key);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    // A potentially "unsafe" method that gets a value by key.
    // Derived classes can implement it such that it throws an
    // exception if the given key has no associated value.
    public abstract object GetValue(string key);
}

class Derived : Base
{
    // The derived class could do something more interesting then this,
    // but the point here is that it might throw an exception for a given
    // key. In this case, we'll just always throw an exception.
    public override object GetValue(string key)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming G() = GetValue() ?